# What is the exact purpose of the personalization procedure in globalplatform architecture?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

I'm currently engaging in a eUICC project, and as you know, inside eUICC runs the globalplatform OPEN and GP provides fundamental support for eUICC realization. However, I'm intrigued about the concept of "personalization" since I cannot figure out the exact meaning of it in GSMA eUICC spec. I'm not an expert for smart card, so can anyone enlighten me on its purpose? THX

Answer (score 1):

"Personalization" for smart cards / SIM / UICC means usually that data that are specific to this individual card are introduced into the card. That could be cryptographic keys, configuration data, user names and so on.

Note, that due to the fine-granular access right management none of the operations will be permitted later. On the other hand this way the card issuer can perform all identitiy verification checks considered necessary for his type of card /SIM/ etc.

Comment: @guidot You might want to consider posting such information as a comment or even a separate answer instead of editing completely new information into someone else's answer (essentially making it look as if that were [hase](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6852384/hase)'s words^^)